# Vertical page flip

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation

Is it possible to rotate a view so that I can use UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft/Right to create vertical page flips?

Answer (score 0):

The flip transitions are always applied horizontally with respect to the current device orientation. Normally, to do a similar vertical transition, you'd use one of the curl animations, like `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp`. Is there a reason you need to avoid that in your particular application?